# Modeling dependency between two variables

Tags: probability, statistics, mathematical-modeling

I want to model the dependence between two variables. Now there are a few ways to do this, for example writing one variable as a function of the other or using correlation. 
I have also looked into copulas but I was wondering if anyone knows any other way to model the dependence of two variables?

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: What kind of variables are you thinking about ?

Comment: Just two random variables, I would like to make as little assumptions as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the  [Iman and Conover IHQ method](https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/STK4400/v05/undervisningsmateriale/A%20distribution-free%20approach%20to%20rank%20correlation.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a physical model, first have a scatter plot of your data. This could give you an idea of the type of model to work (linear, polynomial, exponential, logarithmic, ...). When you have selected the model, regression (linear or non linear) techniques will need to be used (least squares methods). If the physical model is already available, similar methods will allow you to fine tune the model parameters.

Comment: Yes, you write one variable as a function of the other. Also I do not have any physical data, I am trying to construct a mathematical dependence only, such as copulas or correlations (linear, spearman, etc).